# How can I log a messages to a Oracle 11g database with Nlog in ASP.NET VNEXT (MVC 6)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core, nlog

I am new to VNEXT. I have tried with

"NLog.Config": "4.3.4",
"NLogEx": "1.0.11",
"NLog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final-2016-02-06", 
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog": "1.0.0-rc1-final"

Also

"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc2-final"

not able to complie.

Its giving error.

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   NU1002 The dependency Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions
>   1.0.0-rc2-final in project NLog.Web.AspNetCore does not support framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1. NLog.Web.AspNetCore
>   D:\MVC6\NLog.Web-master\NLog.W‌​eb.AspNetCore\project.json 1

Not able to figured it out.

Comment: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web

Comment: "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc2-final"  not able to complie. Its giving error. Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error NU1002 The dependency Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions 1.0.0-rc2-final in project NLog.Web.AspNetCore does not support framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1. NLog.Web.AspNetCore D:\MVC6\NLog.Web-master\NLog.Web.AspNetCore\project.json 1

Comment: You can't mix rc1 with rc2. Also you should check which which packages do work. And be sure your vs2015 and nuget are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, it doesn't support .NET Framework 4.5.1

It will work with 4.6 thought:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
```